# Why are variables not inheriting in subclass in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two classes. A Person class and a Patient class, with Person being the parent and Patient being the child. I have the variables `firstName` and `lastName` and the variable `name` is the combination of both in the Person class, like so:

```
public Person (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
    firstName = initialFirstName;
    lastName = initialLastName;
    name = firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

But when I want the Patient class to inherit these variables, it won't.

```
public Patient (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
    super(initialFirstName);
    super(initialLastName);
}
```

I'm not sure why it won't work. The only thing I can come up with is that you can't have two supers when inheriting variables, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It should be `super(initialFirstName, initialLastName);` Not two super

Comment: This is not a non-inheritance problem. You are calling a non-existent base class constructor.

Comment: Sounds like a visibility problem. If your variables are declared as private, the Patient class cannot access those. To be sure, we need more of your classes. What do you mean exactly by "it won't inherit these variables"? Additionally you have a syntactic error. The super constructor can only be called once and not twice like in your code.

Comment: @ajheilman please read this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public Patient (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
   super(initialFirstName,initialLastName);
}
```

instead of

```
public Patient (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
    super(initialFirstName);
    super(initialLastName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Invocation of a [superclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) constructor ***must be the first line in the
>   subclass constructor.***

Anyway, below line of code should give you compilation error

```
public Patient (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
    super(initialFirstName);
    super(initialLastName);
}
```

It should be

```
public Patient (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
    super(initialFirstName, initialLastName);
}
```

Also, please note that,

> With super(parameter list), the superclass constructor with a ***matching parameter list is called***.

So, referring to you code `super(initialFirstName);` give you compilation error as there aren't matching parameter list constructor defined in super class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
public Patient (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
   super(initialFirstName,initialLastName);
}
```

Or if those two field are protected or public and you don't want set by constructor then you can try this

```
public Patient (String initialFirstName, String initialLastName){
   super.firstName = initialFirstName;
   super.lastName = initialLastName;
}
```